# How can I search an element in an array with strcmp

Tags: c, for-loop, return-type, strcmp, function-definition

Animal is a struct and name is one of its attribute.
What I want is when I write a name in scanf, it should iterate in the array uing strcmp and when it returns 0 then it should print that index in the array.

```
void SearchAnimalName(Animal *animalName, uint8_t number_of_animals)
{
    char search[10];
    scanf("%s", search);

    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_animals; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(search, (animalName + i)->name) == 0)
        {

            return animalName->name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what incorrect behaviour or error do you get with your code? If you want to print the index then why are you not calling `printf` anywhere? Please provide complete code as a [mre] as well as the exact input, expected result and actual result. As a new user please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Your function is declared with `void` return type so you should not be returning anything from the function. To print the index replace the current `return animalName->name;` with `printf("%d\n", i); return;`

Comment: Even if you change the return type to actually be able to return a value, then you must make sure to return a value in all branches of the function, including if you fail to find anything and the loop just ends.

Answer (score 0):

Your function has the return type `void`.

```
void SearchAnimalName(Animal *animalName, uint8_t number_of_animals)
```

That is it returns nothing and the compiler should issue a message for this return statement

```
return animalName->name;
```

Also it is unclear why the second parameter has the type `uint8_t` and at the same time you are using a variable of the type `int` within the for loop.
.

```
for (int i = 0; i < number_of_animals; i++)
```

If you want to return the index then the function should be declared like

```
size_t SearchAnimalName( const Animal *animalName,  size_t number_of_animals)
{
    char search[10];
    scanf("%9s", search);

    size-t i = 0;

    while ( i < number_of_animals && strcmp(search, animalName[i].name) != 0 )
    {
        i++;
    }

    return i;
}
```

The function returns the index of the found element or the array size in case when the target element is not found.

To output the index you need to use the conversion specifier `zu` as for example

```
size_t i = SearchAnimalName( animalName, number_of_animals );

if ( i != number_of_animals ) printf( "i = %zu\n", i );
```

Comment: instead of just printing the i value, how can I write in a way I can get the element from the struct array.
the struct array is 

Animal animals[25];
it contains int int char